# Replace text surrounding a wildcard in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, regex, php, replacement

So, many years ago when I started writing PHP code, I learned to format information sent from a form as such:

`$_POST[itemnamehere];`

Whether that was right or wrong at the time, it worked. However, with newer versions of PHP, the format needs to contain inverted commas inside the square brackets, like so:

`$_POST['itemnamehere'];`

I have literally thousands of PHP files which contain the former formatting and was hoping to find a way to bulk replace using Notepad++.

Obviously, I can't just replace [ with [' and ] with '] as there will be times when [ and ] are used without it being related to $_POST.

I figure there must be a method via regex in Notepad++, but can't seem to manage it.

Any experts have the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The regex itself is pretty simple.

Search what : `$_POST\[(.+)\]`

Replace with : `$_POST\['$1']`

Search mode : Regular expression

`\.` matches newline : Off

You could use the "Find in Files" search dialog.

Comment: You need to add the inverted commas.

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio: They were there, but for formatting errors they were not displayed.

Comment: Thank you, I was close myself but was using .* rather than (.+).

Comment: fixed the quoting